Building rear track wheel from road wheel
How doable would it be to build a track wheel out of a rear road wheel rim and a track hub? What considerations would need to be made? Spoke count surely will have to match between the hub and rim. What else? I know the basics of truing a wheel and I have access to a spoke wrench and truing stand.

Plausible.
You're right, the spoke count on the hub and the rim have to match - if they didn't then there would be different length spokes all around the rim, as well as a bridge in either the hub or rim that is unsupported for a gap.
Additionally you have to have spokes that are the right length for your combination.  They don't have to be new, but they need to be clean.
As for nipples, just buy new ones.  You might choose to use aluminium for weight, but realistically the savings are minimal and they strip out easily.  Use decent new brass nipples, and you can find them chromed or anodised if you want a colour.
Aside - the rim can be anything you like - a "true" track-only bike has no brakes so no need for a brake track meaning you could use a disk brake rim.  But your existing road bike rim should work fine as long as it is fairly flat.  Building a wheel on a bent rim is no fun.

Another approach might be to use your existing road wheel as-is but fit a "single speed adapter"  which is a cassette with only one cog.  They have spacers to get your chainline straight by placing the cog in the right offset.

I didn't know about the single speed adapter. That sounds much easier! thanks for the insight.

One of my clubmates is building a single-speed setup just using a cog from a cassette and spacers, but if this is actually for track use you've got a problem: Track bikes are fixed, not singlespeed, and the fixed wheel is your only brake.  So having a freehub would be a very bad idea

@ChrisH the SS adapter kit I remember reading about had some way to lock up the freehub.  Vague idea that it had some horizontal screws that went into the hub?  Or maybe bolted to/around/behind the flange somehow?  Can't remember exactly but you're right, it was intended to be a brake as well.

Interesting. I'd want something very convincing if it was to be my only brake (as on the track). For road use with a front brake I might be more willing. There are also ways to use a 6-bolt rotor mount for a fixed cog, flipping the wheel

It does depend on the road rim. Rear wheels for derailleur gears are dished, which means the left hand spokes are longer and looser than the right hand (ds) spokes, to keep the rim central where the hub is not symmetrical.
In order to even up the forces, many rear rims have an offset drilling orare themselves asymmetrical.
A track hub is always symmetrical so to get the best wheelbuild possible, so must the rim be. This usually mean that if a road rim has front or rear options (like Pacenti Forza, some Velocity models etc), fir a track rear wheel, you use the Front rim.
Otherwise, as you say, match the hub drilling to the rim drilling, take your measurements (ERD, hub flange) and calculate length for your cross pattern (2X, 3X). Easy!

Thanks for the insight! So I should choose a rim that has is meant to be symmetrical and find compatible spoke lengths.
